# Storing Data From List To Another Form VS2008

Tags: vb.net

I don't know exactly how to explain this but I'll try.

Is it possible to store or transfer data from a List to another form?
Like for example, I have 20 questions and the answers are being stored in a list. If the user clicks on "review answers" button, another form will pop up showing the questions and the user's answers to those questions.

Sorry I don't really have a code to post as I have no idea how to do this or if this can be done at all.

**UPDATE 1**

I am using List (Of String).. I need the values that are being stored in my List (Of String) to be passed to another form on button click

Comment: Questions like this are asked very often. Please search the forum or check the "related" questions after writing the title.

Comment: Sorry I am fairly new to VB and I don't really know what to search for :(
Let me check the above link.. Thank you..

Comment: Sorry I think this is not what I am looking for.. I am using List (Of String).. I need the values that are being stored in my List (Of String) to be passed to another form on button click

Comment: Just because the answer uses `String` that doesn't mean you have to. Replace `String` with whatever type you want. In such answers the data type is usually not relevant and can be replaced by any other data type you'd like, it's the principle that matters. That question is an exact duplicate and shows you two different ways of passing data from one form to another, whether you want to pass it via a property or method.

Comment: You should really read further into the book. Hold off on writing your first big app until it gets to the part about object-oriented design. Visual Vincent is right, this question is asked dizzyingly often, and almost always points to a deficiency in understanding good design, particularly encapsulation. One form should not need to access private data of another form. And if this is *truly* public data, then it should be made global. And, yes, you should feel dirty about that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use global variables to pass data from one from to another

maybe your list of QSN,ANS should look like

```
        Dim Question As New List(Of String)
        Question.Add("A")
        Question.Add("B")
        Dim Ans As New List(Of String)
        ans.Add("Ans A")
        ans.Add("Ans B")
```

Here how you declare the global The class can be define anywhere in the application.

```
Public Class GlobalVariables
Public Shared Question As String 
Public Shared Answer As String
End Class
```

And how you use global variable to store the answer is here

```
GlobalVariables.Question=Question.Item(<Question list Index Number>)
GlobleVariables.Answer=Ans.Item(<Question list Index Number>)
```

put this two lines in button click event and you can access the variable to any of your form that is in your WINDOWS application.

And how you print or store the value of this variable is

```
Dim A as String = GlobleVariables.Answer
```

Comment: I see... the "calm down don't worry" thing is a theme for you. Please stop saying things like this. I edited it out.

Comment: This might actually be a more valid case where you'd use shared variables. Just keep in mind that the OP wanted access to _**all**_ the answers and questions, not just one of each.

Comment: @VisualVincent No issue on that because we can also create a global List as the same way or he might use an array so that he can access all the question and answer at any form or class in his application...

Comment: **I know we can**, but I pointed it out _**to you**_ because you are the answerer and should write your answer according to the OP's question.

Comment: Ok i'll keep this in mind from next time thanks for the advice....@VisualVincent